# Kotlin Coroutines How to get CoroutineScope for the current Thread?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Kotlin Coroutines, want to create a reference for the current thread and use it later.

```
fun myFuncion(){
    //save current Thread CoroutineScope
    var currentCoroutineScope : CoroutineScope // <How to create?>
    GlobalScope.launch { 
        //Do something 001
        currentCoroutineScope .launch {
            //Do something 002

        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. I'd like to invoke a suspend func in another scope and then invoke other methods on original scope. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: The only solution I used is:- passing the scope as a parameter of the function.

Answer (score 3):

```kotlin
import kotlin.coroutines.coroutineContext

suspend fun somewhere() {
  val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)
  scope.launch { ... }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't simply making a scope with coroutineScope work?
e.g. `import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope` and in your function define `coroutineScope { <now you have access to coroutine scope via "this">}`

Answer (score 2):

You can save a reference to a Coroutines scope using

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
```

and then you can use it like

```
fun myFuncion() {
    scope.launch {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Update from comments:**

if you are calling your `myFunction()` from main thread then you can do something like this

```
fun myFuncion() {
        scope.launch {
            // do something
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { 
                //Do something 002
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working. Even If I call the myFucntion from "main"  "// do something" is running on "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2" (for example)

Comment: @SudarNimalan it will run on whatever dispatcher you will set in `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)` . you can change the default to `io` etc

Comment: I want to make sure "//Do something 002" to run on the same scope of myFunction

Comment: Thank you - I don't want to hardcode "Dispatchers.Main" if myFunction call from other Scope I want to use that scope.